# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer(i am using input() as string not int)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, debugging

I was making  a hangman game in python
but I got this error
I know if I am using integer from input I use int(x)
but I am just using input as string
I should not be getting this error

```
import random
stages = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
word_list = ['random', 'words', 'etc']
print("guess a letter")
tries = 6
word = random.choice(word_list).lower()
word_display = '_'*len(word)
print('the word is '+word)
print(f'>{word_display}')
while tries:
    choice = input('>').lower()
    print(choice)
    if choice in word and choice not in word_display:
        for i in range(word):
            if choice == word[i]:
                word_display[i].replace(choice)
    else:
        tries -= 1
        print(stages[tries])
```

when I give the correct letter
the error occurs here is the error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/pyt/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 14, in <module>
    for i in range(word):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(word))` is what you should use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the length of the word as a string object cannot be iterated. range() in python accepts only integer. Try range(len(word))